# Do i need a separate powerswitch for amplifier besides remote

Tags: battery, audio, wiring, battery-drain

I have a Ford Fiesta 2010 model. Its fitted with **JBL GT5-A402** amplifier with 240 watt. It is connected to a Pioneer head unit. Rem wire is working fine. Amplifier is powered directly by the battery with fuse and proper gauge wire. The power light will always be ON even if the head unit is switched OFF. But the light behind the JBL logo will turn on when the head unit ON.

My questions are
1) Do i need a separate power switch for the amplifier? Will it drain the battery?
2) Can i use a bed switch of 230v AC 6A for this?
3) I am having 40AH battery, will it drain if i use the amplifier while driving?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1) This depends on how the power wire is connected. If it is connected directly to the battery (via a fuse, of course), the switch will be useful. If it is powered only when the key is in the Acc position, no separate switch is needed.

2) Yes.

3) Provided your alternator is OK (so the battery is charged when driving), I would say you are absolutely fine.

Comment: I have connected the amplifier directly to the battery with a fuse. 1)Will it drain battery during stopped the vehicle for a week? So many told me the AC switch will burn out due to over current flow. I am planning to control the ground terminal through the switch. So the gauge might lover as compared to the current wiring. 2) Will it burn?

Comment: I've got the answer for all my questions. I am controlling rem wire using a switch and relay. Now it's working perfectly. Please update the answer with the link below https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378265/can-we-switch-ground-in-relay